# Remove Row if NaN in First Five Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe with dimensions 89 rows by 13 columns. I want to remove an **entire** row *if* `NaN` appears within the first five columns. Here is an example.

```
LotName     C15   C16  C17  C18  C19 Spots15 Spots16 ...
Cherry St   439   464  555  239  420     101     101 ...
Springhurst NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      12      12
Barton Lot   34    24   43   45   39      10       9 ...
```

In the above example, I would want to remove the *Springhurst* observation, as it contains `NaN` within the first five columns. How would I be able to do this in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you want to do a strict check of `Nan` in all rows for first 5 columns:**

```
df.iloc[:, :5].dropna(how='all')
```

Explanation:

`df.iloc[:, :5]` : select all rows and first 5 columns

`.dropna(how='all')` : check if all values in a row are `NaN`

**If you want to check for `Nan` in any of the 5 columns:**

```
df.iloc[:, :5].dropna(how='any')
```

### For assigning it back to original df, you can do this:

```
In [2107]: ix = df.iloc[:, :5].dropna(how='all').index.tolist()

In [2110]: df = df.loc[ix]

In [2111]: df
Out[2111]: 
       LotName    C15    C16    C17    C18  C19  Spots15  Spots16
Cherry      St  439.0  464.0  555.0  239.0  420      101    101.0
Barton     Lot   34.0   24.0   43.0   45.0   39       10      9.0
```

Comment: Will this statement remove the rows from the original dataframe?

Comment: @Bill I've updated my answer to remove rows from original df. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iloc` to select your columns, `notna()` for not `NaN`, and `any` to check if any of the values in selected columns/rows is True

```
mask = df.iloc[:,:5].notna().any(axis=1)
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
              C15    C16    C17    C18    C19  Spots15 Spots16 ...
LotName                                                           
Cherry St   439.0  464.0  555.0  239.0  420.0      101     101 ...
Barton Lot   34.0   24.0   43.0   45.0   39.0       10       9 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: here you can specify the columns, from `C15` to `C19` and then filter-out all rows which have any NaN inside:

```
print( df[~df.loc[:, 'C15':'C19'].isna().any(axis=1)] )
```

Prints:

```
      LotName    C15    C16    C17    C18    C19  Spots15  Spots16
0   Cherry St  439.0  464.0  555.0  239.0  420.0      101      101
2  Barton Lot   34.0   24.0   43.0   45.0   39.0       10        9
```