# How to delete rows from pandas data frame if list of columns values are NULL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame in pandas with following columns .
A, B, C, D , X, y, z

I want to delete the rows from the Data frame if A,B,C,D all the 4 columns values are null .
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Row if NaN in First Five Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528034/remove-row-if-nan-in-first-five-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `dropna(how='all')`:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: @GyanaranjanNayak Please let me know if the answer worked?

Comment: @GyanaranjanNayak Did the answer work for you? Its not nice when someone helps you by giving answers and don't get awarded any points in return.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Comment: I think this will drop if any one pf this value is NULL . But I want If all the A,B,C,D values are null then drop that row .